# Insert multiple lines Containing ' and $variable using sed not working

Tags: shell, sed, solaris

I am new to scripting and stuck at one place that may be really simple.. still would be grateful if anyone can help.

**Below is my issue in simplest term:**

**Input file new.txt**

*Hello team*

**Output file expected:** new_2.txt

```
  Select '/backup/path1_' from dual;
  Select '/backup/path2_' from dual;  
    Hello team
```

---

**Note :** *$var1=path1 and $var2=path2*

```
Sed command used : 
Sed '1i\
Select '/backup/"$var1"_' from dual;\
Select '/backup/"$var2"_' from dual;\
' new.txt > new_2.txt
```

**Output received:**

```
new_2.txt 
Select /backup/path1_ from dual;
Select /backup/path2_from dual;

Hello team
```

---

After various quotes combination also, either single quote ' won't be displayed in output or var value won't be inserted.

Comment: The sed/Sed/SED program is invoked by writing `sed`, not `Sed`. Furhtermore, please do not include explanations in code; for instance, _Sed command used :_ is likely part of your question, not of any file. Please, adjust your question accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

Would you please try the following:

```
var1=path1
var2=path2
sed "1i\\
Select '/backup/${var1}_' from dual;\\
Select '/backup/${var2}_' from dual;
" new.txt > new_2.txt
```

Result:

```
Select '/backup/path1_' from dual;
Select '/backup/path2_' from dual;
Hello team
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also escape the quotes mark with a backslash:

```
sed '1i\
Select '\'/backup/"$var1"_\'' from dual;\
Select '\'/backup/"$var2"_\'' from dual;
' new.txt > new_2.txt
```